# I would like to make a custom domain on my own nameserver

Tags: domains, dns, nameserver, dns-servers

If I set up my own nameserver/and or a DNS server, How would I go about making my own custom domains?
Please correct me if I am wrong about needing a nameserver/and or a DNS server

Comment: Why do you think you need your own DNS server?   If you are running a website, you can use a DNS server that is provided by your domain registrar or webhost.  If they don't have them available you can use third party domain hosting for as little as $10/year.   DNS services are cheap.  If you want to run your own you need multiple servers in different countries. DNS servers are difficult to run and  hard to secure.  I would not recommend running your own DNS server.

Comment: I want to be able to have my own custom domain/domain extension. Also, I want one for privacy reasons

Comment: I also don't want mine to be at scale. I want mine to be local with a backup to 1.1.1.1

Comment: You don't need your own DNS server for a custom domain name.  Privacy for whois data is handled by the registrar no matter your choice of DNS server.

Comment: What do you mean you want yours to be local? The domains you want to make, should they be accessible from the outside? If not, you can just edit your hosts file.

Comment: I thought he meant he wanted to run a domain name server locally.  Not sure what a backup to 1.1.1.1 means though.

Comment: I would like to have a domain extension that is not available through a domain registrar. Basically, I would like to bypass ICANN and make my own server to process the requests. A backup to 1.1.1.1 means that if a domain is not available on my server it will send a request to the DNS server 1.1.1.1 (cloudflare)

Comment: "I would like to have a domain extension that is not available through a domain registrar. ".  You can't. If you want it to be globally available and visible of course. If it is a local experiment, you can set up your nameservers with whatever domain and TLD you wish. But by default noone will query for them. Also you seem to be mixing or not to be clear on the very important difference between an authoritative nameserver (the kind you will need to create domains) and a recursive nameserver (the kind `1.1.1.1` is).

Comment: I don't want mine to be globally viable I want to have somebody directly connect to my nameserver and access a custom domain I made.

Comment: Something like OpenNIC but not at that scale

Comment: This question is really too [broadly-scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for this site, which is specific to [operating websites](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) - advanced questions about [system and network administration](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are better asked over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). (Please don't duplicate previously asked off-topic questions).

Comment: Ok, I thought this would be better suited for ProWebmasters. If needed please migrate this to Server Fault

Answer (score 2):

You can't eliminate the registrar and domain servers entirely, as no browser could find your domain. So no, what you want isn't really possible

A domain must be registered through an ICANN accredited registrar. That's what the ".com" or such points to, then their servers say "check *domain registrar* for more info"

Even if you could get this up and running, you may get in trouble (unless you create your own registrar, which is expensive and not easy)

There really would be no gain doing it yourself anyway, because Cloudflare had a global CDN you don't have, and a lot more server power